# Issue with Download Button Functionality in Shiny App for Metric Selection in an R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently developing a Shiny app for visualizing and analyzing data. One of the features allows users to select multiple metrics and then download the selected metrics as a csv or text file using a download button.

I'm facing an issue where the download button doesn't seem to work as expected. i need to dowload just t[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYDAQ.png)he checked parameters

```
 # RR output
      output$rmse_output_rr <- renderText({
        if (input$display_rr) {
          rmse_rr <- sqrt(mean((rr_data$simul_complete - rr_data$obs_complete)^2))
          sprintf("RMSE of RR: %.2f mm", rmse_rr)
        }
      })

      output$biais_output_rr <- renderText({
        if (input$display_rr) {
          biais_rr <- mean(rr_data$simul_complete - rr_data$obs_complete)
          sprintf("Biais of RR: %.2f mm", biais_rr)
        }
      })

      output$Corr_output_rr <- renderText({
        if (input$display_rr) {
          corr_rr <- cor(rr_data$simul_complete, rr_data$obs_complete)
          sprintf("Correlation of RR: %.2f", corr_rr)
        }
      })

      output$cv_output_rr <- renderText({
        if (input$display_rr) {
          cv_rr <- (sd(rr_data$simul_complete, na.rm = TRUE) / mean(rr_data$simul_complete, na.rm = TRUE)) * 100
          sprintf("Coefficient of Variation (CV) of RR: %.2f%%", cv_rr)
        }
      })

      # Tmax output
      output$rmse_output_tmax <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmax) {
          rmse_tmax <- sqrt(mean((tmax_data$simul_complete - tmax_data$obs_complete)^2))
          sprintf("RMSE of Tmax: %.2f °C", rmse_tmax)
        }
      })

      output$biais_output_tmax <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmax) {
          biais_tmax <- mean(tmax_data$simul_complete - tmax_data$obs_complete)
          sprintf("Biais of Tmax: %.2f °C", biais_tmax)
        }
      })

      output$Corr_output_tmax <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmax) {
          corr_tmax <- cor(tmax_data$simul_complete, tmax_data$obs_complete)
          sprintf("Correlation of Tmax: %.2f", corr_tmax)
        }
      })

      output$cv_output_tmax <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmax) {
          cv_tmax <- (sd(tmax_data$simul_complete, na.rm = TRUE) / mean(tmax_data$simul_complete, na.rm = TRUE)) * 100
          sprintf("Coefficient of Variation (CV) of Tmax: %.2f%%", cv_tmax)
        }
      })

      # Tmin output
      output$rmse_output_tmin <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmin) {
          rmse_tmin <- sqrt(mean((tmin_data$simul_complete - tmin_data$obs_complete)^2))
          sprintf("RMSE of Tmin: %.2f °C", rmse_tmin)
        }
      })

      output$biais_output_tmin <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmin) {
          biais_tmin <- mean(tmin_data$simul_complete - tmin_data$obs_complete)
          sprintf("Biais of Tmin: %.2f °C", biais_tmin)
        }
      })

      output$Corr_output_tmin <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmin) {
          corr_tmin <- cor(tmin_data$simul_complete, tmin_data$obs_complete)
          sprintf("Correlation of Tmin: %.2f", corr_tmin)
        }
      })

      output$cv_output_tmin <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmin) {
          cv_tmin <- (sd(tmin_data$simul_complete, na.rm = TRUE) / mean(tmin_data$simul_complete, na.rm = TRUE)) * 100
          sprintf("Coefficient of Variation (CV) of Tmin: %.2f%%", cv_tmin)
        }
      })

      # Tmoy output
      output$rmse_output_tmoy <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmoy) {
          rmse_tmoy <- sqrt(mean((tmoy_data_simul - tmoy_data_obs)^2))
          sprintf("RMSE of Tmoy: %.2f °C", rmse_tmoy)
        }
      })

      output$biais_output_tmoy <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmoy) {
          biais_tmoy <- mean(tmoy_data_simul - tmoy_data_obs)
          sprintf("Biais of Tmoy: %.2f °C", biais_tmoy)
        }
      })

      output$Corr_output_tmoy <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmoy) {
          corr_tmoy <- cor(tmoy_data_simul, tmoy_data_obs)
          sprintf("Correlation of Tmoy: %.2f", corr_tmoy)
        }
      })

      output$cv_output_tmoy <- renderText({
        if (input$display_tmoy) {
          cv_tmoy <- (sd(tmoy_data_simul, na.rm = TRUE) / mean(tmoy_data_simul, na.rm = TRUE)) * 100
          sprintf("Coefficient of Variation (CV) of Tmoy: %.2f%%", cv_tmoy)
        }
      })
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a minimal reproducible example. It's very hard for anyone to help you without one

Comment: I posted my answer for two purposes med: (1) attempt to answer your problem with downloading files; and (2) demonstrate what a _reproducible_ example can look like. In the case of the answer, it is completely self-contained, it works as-is, and does not require you to have knowledge of any resources/files/processes on my end. Please think about this when you ask your next questions, it really helps us to have more context than you've provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'll create my own content that includes some input fields and two (for variety) `downloadButton`s, one each for JSON and CSV formats. (I offer JSON in many of my shiny apps because some of our parameters are multi-faceted, which does not lend as well to tabular structures without reshaping to a long format.)

(I have both an input field and a disabled textual description because it seems from the image of your page that you are doing something similar. For an even more basic approach, we could get rid of all `textInput`, `updateTextInput`

```r
library(shiny)
# library(shinyjs)
# library(jsonlite)      # optional for json download
# library(shinyvalidate) # optional

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton("dl_json", "Download JSON", icon = icon("file-code")),
      downloadButton("dl_csv", "Download CSV", icon = icon("file-csv"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      numericInput("var1", "Variable 1", value = round(pi, 2)),
      numericInput("var2", "Variable 2", value = round(exp(1), 2)),
      br(),
      textInput("txt1", "Description of variable 1", placeholder = "(uncalculated)"),
      textInput("txt2", "Description of variable 2", placeholder = "(uncalculated)")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shinyjs::disable("txt1")
  shinyjs::disable("txt2")

  # optional but useful and unambiguous to the user
  iv <- shinyvalidate::InputValidator$new()
  iv$add_rule("var1", shinyvalidate::sv_numeric())
  iv$add_rule("var2", shinyvalidate::sv_numeric())
  iv$enable()

  vars <- reactiveValues(var1=NULL, var2=NULL, var1d=NULL, var2d=NULL)
  observeEvent(input$var1, {
    validate(
      need(!is.na(input$var1), "Var1 needs to be a valid 'numeric'")
    )
    vars$var1d <- sprintf("Variable 1 is set to: %.01f", input$var1)
    vars$var1 <- input$var1
    updateTextInput(session, "txt1", value = vars$var1d)
  })
  observeEvent(input$var2, {
    validate(
      need(!is.na(input$var2), "Var2 needs to be a valid 'numeric'")
    )
    vars$var2d <- sprintf("Variable 2 is set to: %.02f", input$var2)
    vars$var2 <- input$var2
    updateTextInput(session, "txt2", value = vars$var2d)
  })
  output$dl_json <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "variables.json",
    content = function(file) {
      json <- jsonlite::toJSON(reactiveValuesToList(vars), pretty = TRUE) # pretty only if you want
      writeLines(json, file)
    }
  )
  output$dl_csv <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "variables.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      dat <- as.data.frame(reactiveValuesToList(vars))
      write.csv(dat, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With this, we see a simple austere shiny app that could really use some design improvements :-)

[image: very simple shiny app]

From here, if you click on `Download JSON`, you get a file named `"variables.json"` with contents:

```
{
  "var2d": ["Variable 2 is set to: 2.72"],
  "var1d": ["Variable 1 is set to: 3.1"],
  "var2": [2.72],
  "var1": [3.14]
}
```

If you click on `Download CSV`, you get a file named `"variables.csv"` with contents:

```
"var2d","var1d","var2","var1"
"Variable 2 is set to: 2.72","Variable 1 is set to: 3.1",2.72,3.14
```

If you're curious, the use of `shinyvalidator` presents some clear guidance when rules are violated:

[image: shiny with a validation rule broken]

When used in combination with `validate(need(..))`, it prevents bad values from cascading into other components and causing failures.

I use a `reactiveValues` for storing validated variable numbers so that we always have valid values for dependent calculations. This means that whatever else might be needing the validated numbers (e.g., the `downloadHandler`s) should use the `vars` reactive values list.